# Android: Viewpager refresh, edit text won't refresh

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I wanted my view pager to call `onCreate` every time so am using the below code:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) 
{
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser && isChanged())
    {
        isChanged = false;
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();

        viewPagerUpdatedInterface.viewPagerUpdated(); // inteface called in main method this will  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Here I am able to see correct value of string which I needed to update in logs but the same is not showing on screen.

My adapter class is below:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your requirement exactly? Please clarify.